# Creating a file with input user, using strings with spaces (C)

Tags: c

I'm working with files and trying to create one with user's text input, but some of the input must allow different words with spaces between. I've been looking for solutions here, I suppose the best option is to use **fgets** but it only works for **text input** while **subject input** only prints the text in the file after two words, I would like to know how to print in the file the whole subject input.

THANKS!!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int id=0;
    char to[20], from[20], date[10], subject[40], text[1000];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("outbox/email.txt","w");

    printf("\nTo: ");
    scanf("%s",&to);
    printf("\nFrom: ");
    scanf("%s", &from);
    printf("\nID: %d\n", id);
    printf("\nDate: ");
    scanf("%s", &date);
    printf("\nSubject: ");
    scanf("%s",&subject);
    printf("\nText: ");
    scanf("%s",&text);

    fprintf(fp,"To: %s     ",to);
    fprintf(fp, "From: %s     ", from);
    fprintf(fp, "ID: %d     ", id);
    fprintf(fp, "Date: %s     ", date);
    fgets(subject,40,stdin);
    fprintf(fp, "Subject: %s     ", subject);
    fgets(text,1000,stdin);
    fprintf(fp, "Text: %s     ", text);

    fclose(fp);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf("%s", str)` reads only one word. `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)` reads a whole line. It seems to me that you want to read in a whole line for each header item, since they are all usually made out of multiple words. So use `fgets()` everywhere.

Also, the sizes you use for the strings are quite small. It's easy to have an email address that is longer than 19 characters for example.